# Git clone ask for password

Tags: git, authentication, ssh

I have followed this how-to to configure a GIT server in my VPS server:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

but each time I try to clone from my workstation (I generated key and added to authorized_keys) it asks me for GIT user password!

Why? how can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: You can't clone a private repository

Answer (score 5):

You are cloning from an http URL which will not use your SSH keys and ask for your password. You can either clone using a SSH connection or install password caching. GitHub has nice instructions to set this up: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching